# mongodb not responding after save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose for my express.js project.

Here is my article model:

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({

    type: String
    ,title: String
    ,content: String

    ,comments: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId
        ,ref: 'Comment'
    }]

    ,replies: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId
        ,ref: 'Reply'
    }]


    ,feedbacks: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId
        ,ref: 'Feedback'
    }]


    ,meta: {
        tags: [String] //anything
        ,apps: [{
            store: String //app store, google play, amazon app store
            ,storeId: String
        }]
        ,category: String
    }


    , status: String
    ,statusMeta: {
        createdBy: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId
            ,ref: 'User'
        }
        ,createdDate: Date
        , updatedBy: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId
            ,ref: 'User'
        }
        ,updatedDate: Date

        ,deletedBy: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
        ,deletedDate: Date

        ,undeletedBy: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
        ,undeletedDate: Date

        ,bannedBy: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
        ,bannedDate: Date
        ,unbannedBy: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }

        ,unbannedDate: Date
    }
}, {minimize: false})
```

This is my controller function

```
exports.createArticle = function(req, res, next) {

    //1. save article
    var newArticle = new Article()
    newArticle.status = helper.constant.entityStatus.normal
    newArticle.type = req.body.type
    newArticle.category = req.body.category
    newArticle.title = req.body.title
    newArticle.content = req.body.content
    //comments omit
    //replies omit
    //feedbacks omit
    newArticle.meta = req.body.meta
    newArticle.statusMeta.createdBy = req.user
    newArticle.statusMeta.createdDate = new Date
    newArticle.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            return next(err)

        //2. add article to user
        req.user.articles.push(newArticle)
        req.user.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                return next(err)

            //3. refetch article, done
            var query = Article.findById(newArticle._id)
            helper.populateCommonFieldsForQuery(query)
            query.exec(function(err, article) {
                if (err)
                    return next(err)
                if (! article)
                    return next(helper.getGeneralError('unable to fetch saved article'))
                return res.json(helper.dataAppendedWithMessage(article.toJSON(), 'success', 'successfully created article'))
            })
        })

    })
}
```

When I create article with `meta.tags` to be an empty array, everything works. If the tags are not empty, then the save callback (`function(err) {}`)is not fired.

Comment: Probably this is not good: `tags: [String]` Is it a string or an array? it should be `tags: []`or `tags: String` but not both.

Comment: it's an array of strings

Comment: So tags: [] is sufficient

Comment: @Michelem `[ String ]` is Mongoose's way of stating that it's an array of strings. Perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a bug with my own code. inside `helper.js` I used `helper.functionName()` instead of `exports.functionName()`, which is undefined. It's so hard to catch such bugs in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Before save write this:

```
newArticle.markModified('meta');
```